Which parts of "Ender's Game" movie were taken from "Ender's Shadow" book?
I just ran into this interesting tidbit of information in a comment on SFF.SE:

The movie ..is also based on two books at once, Ender's Game and Ender's Shadow. Per word of the creator. – Therac; Commented Mar 21, 2020 at 14:30

Assuming this info is accurate: which parts of "Ender's Shadow" were reflected in the movie? (obviously I'm interested in only the parts that were different between the two books; whether contradictions or additions).

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1731141/faq/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/1pnuw3/comment/cd6hw2s/ suggests that most of the Ender's Shadow material is basically the details that Ender didn't take note of because Ender's Game is all about Ender's thought process, not what's going on in the world around him.
